# If a name server is down for a while, does the registrar change DNS of my domain because arent working

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-hosting

I have an infrastructure with my own nameservers, and these servers were offline for a week. On the server, there are many websites managed through WHM/CPANEL. After recovering the infrastructure, some sites came back online, but others did not.

The ones that haven't come back are those registered with Tucows Domains. When I check the WHOIS information for those domains, it shows:

Name Servers:
drop-a1c7e94a-xxx.empty.as112.arpa
drop-d37bf1b8-xxx.empty.as112.arpa

Is it possible that the registrar (Tucows) changed the DNS because the original ones were offline?

Comment: No. Why not contact the registrar?

Comment: Some TLD require working name servers before they allow registration of your desired  domain, like for example the [pre registration check Denic performs](https://www.denic.de/fileadmin/public/documentation/DENIC-23p_EN.pdf) for .DE domains. I'm not sure if Denic does, but it does stand to reason that such TLD domains might also invalidate your domain when your name servers no longer meet the registration requirements and stop responding. But as already suggested, ask your registrar.

Comment: Those name servers are associated with the AS112 Project. Why or how that's relevant to your problem, I have no idea. Your best bet is to contact the Registrar and speak to them. - https://www.ripe.net/analyse/dns/as112/

Comment: the websites are back again, the most probable thing was: like DNS server was offline, then tucows change the not working DNS for a "null" domain like drop-a1c7e94a-xxx.empty.as112.arpa, we changed back the DNS names for a working ones and we are ok.